# Fetching data from the server, saving in 'state', then displaying 'react-trello' on a card

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to fetch data from the server, save them in `this.state.date` and then display them on cards in kanban? I use the `react-trello` library. I read in the documentation to put the data in a json file.

First error:

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data` of type `array` supplied to
>   `BoardContainer`, expected `object`.

Second error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>       at Object.initialiseLanes (LaneHelper.js?bc88:20)
>       at boardReducer (BoardReducer.js?f5a0:20)
>       at dispatch (redux.js?00d8:212)
>       at Object.eval [as loadBoard] (redux.js?00d8:475)
>       at BoardContainer.componentDidMount (BoardContainer.js?90b9:140)
>       at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js?61bb:17334)
>       at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js?61bb:18736)
>       at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?61bb:149)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?61bb:199)
>       at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?61bb:256)

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      date: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodos();
  };

  getTodos = () => {
    axios({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => { 
      this.setState({
        date: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    }) 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>react-trello demo</h1>
        <Board data={this.state.date} draggable />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont see why that wouldnt work..

Comment: What is the question? Whats not working from above code?

Comment: @hamobi I updated my question

Comment: @Rikin  I updated my question

Comment: Your `data` is not a match for `Board`'s prop `data` thus the error, you need to create your own set of data and pass it on to Board component as it expects, head over to their docs to see what sort of data structure it expects

Comment: @Rikin This structure in data.json is correctly https://codesandbox.io/s/1o3zj95m9j. But it is only file data.json, but I want to fetch dates from server. Do you have any idea? How put dates from server in file json?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but your `data` need to match what `<Board>` component is expecting. The way you are trying is correct to fetch the data, it just need to be in the shape your `Board` component expects thus you need to modify your server response to match the exact shape of the response the way `Board` component wants it or massage data in your component before passing it over to `Board` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments and explained [here](https://github.com/rcdexta/react-trello#usage), your data structure needs to be structured like so:

```
{
  "lanes": [
    {
      id: "example",
      title: "example",
      label: "example",
      style: {
        width: 280
      },
      "cards": [
        {
          id: "example",
          title: "example",
          label: "example",
          description: "example"
        },
        ... and so on...
      ]
    },
};
```

Where `lanes` is an array of objects with `id` (required), `title` (optional), `label` (optional), `style` (optional), and `cards` (required) is an array of objects with `id` (required), `title` (optional), `label` (optional), `description` (optional).

As you can see in this [example](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users), the data structure returned from the API doesn't follow the same pattern, so you'll have to build it.

---

**Working example**:

[image: Edit react-trello-example with json placeholder data]

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty";
import axios from "axios";
import Board from "react-trello";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodos();
  }

  getTodos = () => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(res => {
        const data = {
          lanes: [
            {
              id: "applicants",
              title: "Applicants",
              style: { width: 280 },
              cards: res.data.map(user => ({
                id: user.id.toString(),
                title: user.name,
                description: user.email
              }))
            },
            {
              id: "interviewed",
              title: "Interviewed",
              style: { width: 280 },
              cards: []
            }
          ]
        };

        this.setState({ data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>react-trello demo</h1>
        {!isEmpty(data) ? <Board data={data} draggable /> : <p>Loading...</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

---

On a side note, I find this package very opinionated (it has to be) and if you're up for the challenge, I'd encourage you to build your own board. For example, I needed to build a [board](https://ttmj3.csb.app/) ([source](https://codesandbox.io/s/ttmj3)) to handle [JSON Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) because that's what I work with on my back-end (and my front end relies upon it); plus, I find the data structure more flexible than [JSON Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp), although they're much harder to maintain/update.

Comment: And what library would you recommend to carry the cards? I read about: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beautiful-dnd. But here the data structure must also be defined. Structure dates isn't elastic

Comment: The data can be structure however you want/need it to be. YOU (and not a package) have to handle and maintain it. Here's my same board mentioned above, but handling a JSON object: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dnd-moving-between-lists-12rv6